# Getting OData Count in ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

Using the sample code from Hassan Habib's [Supercharging ASP.NET Core API with OData](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/supercharging-asp-net-core-api-with-odata/) blog post, I am  able to get the record count using an OData query of `$count=true`:

[image]

**What needs to be configured to get the response object to be wrapped in an `OData context` so that the `@odata.count` property will show?**

In my own ASP.NET Core web API project, I cannot get the simple `$count` parameter to work and I have no idea why.

With Hassan's sample code, the response JSON is wrapped in an `OData context` and the payload (an `IEnumerable<Student>` object) is in the `value` property of the JSON response.   In my project, the `OData context` wrapper does not exist; my code *never* returns `OData context`, it only returns the payload object of type `IEnumerable<T>`:

[image]

I've also noticed that the `Content-Type` in the response header is `application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true; charset=utf-8` in the sample project, where as it is simply `application/json; charset=utf-8` in my project.  I don't see any setting that controls this in either project, so I'm assuming the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Odata` NuGet package is magically changing the response when it's configured properly.

My project is also using .NET Core 2.2 (Upgraded from 2.1), all the same versions of NuGet packages as Hassan's sample projects, and all the same settings in the `StartUp.cs` class... although my `StartUp.cs` is *way* more complicated (hence the reason I'm not posting it's content here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue when i use `[Route("api/[controller]")]`and `[ApiController]` with the startup.cs like below:

```
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.Expand().Select().Count().OrderBy().Filter();
            routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
        });
```

To fix it,be sure you have built a private method to do a handshake between your existing data models (OData model in this case) and EDM.

Here is a simple demo:

1.Controller(comment on `Route` attribute and `ApiController` attribute):

```
//[Route("api/[controller]")]
//[ApiController]
public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly WSDbContext _context;
    public StudentsController(WSDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    // GET: api/Students
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery()]
    public IEnumerable<Student> Get()
    {
        return _context.Students;
    }
}
//[Route("api/[controller]")]
//[ApiController]
public class SchoolsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly WSDbContext _context;
    public SchoolsController(WSDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    // GET: api/Schools
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery()]
    public IEnumerable<School> Get()
    {
        return _context.Schools;
    }
```

2.Startup.cs():

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore(action => action.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=WSDB;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
        services.AddDbContext<WSDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddOData();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.Expand().Select().Count().OrderBy().Filter();
            routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("api", "api", GetEdmModel());
        });
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Student>("Students");
        builder.EntitySet<Student>("Schools");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving such a detailed answer.  Commenting-out the ```[Route]``` and ```[ApiController]``` attributes seemed to do the trick.  The controller not longer appears in the related Swagger page, but the OData endpoint still exists and now returns the OData context wrapper I was looking for.

Comment: It wasn't necessary for me to remove `[Route]` and `[ApiController]`. `routeBuilder.Expand().Select().Count()` did the trick

Comment: This would disable the api/routing on the existing API calls and require my api's to be requested over odata. In Hassan's non-EDM based approach reason was to extend the existing API capability to support OData. But I can't seem to get $count working without having the need of introducing EDM.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I wanted to extend existing Api methods with `[EnableQuery]` but have it include the count metadata.

I ended up extending the EnableQuery attribute to return a different reponse, it worked perfectly.

```
public class EnableQueryWithMetadataAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);

        if (actionExecutedContext.Result is ObjectResult obj && obj.Value is IQueryable qry)
        {
            obj.Value = new ODataResponse
            {
                Count = actionExecutedContext.HttpContext.Request.ODataFeature().TotalCount,
                Value = qry
            };
        }
    }
    public class ODataResponse
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("@odata.count")]
        public long? Count { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("value")]
        public IQueryable Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach thanks for sharing

Answer (score 4):

Just been battling this.

I found that if I request my controller at `/api/Things` that most of the OData options work but `$count` doesn't.

However, `$count` *does* work if I request the same method via `/odata/Things`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I've created a special action named $count that users the OData Filter query my collection (EF Database) and return the Count;

```
[HttpGet("$count")]
public async Task<int> Count(ODataQueryOptions<MyBookEntity> odataQueryOptions)
{
    var queryable = this.dataContext.MyBooks;

    return await odataQueryOptions.Filter
        .ApplyTo(queryable, new ODataQuerySettings())
        .Cast<MyBookEntity>()
        .CountAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set an empty prefix route when you map OData, and you will receive OData with your request your endpoint.

```
routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataEdmModel", "", GetEdmModel());
```