# How to enable count in OData and .NET Core 3.0 on ASP .NET Application?

Tags: c#, count, odata

When I make a request :
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users?$count=true

It returns the object and the values of its properties but it does not return the count of users:

[image]

This is my action in the controller:

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Gets the list of all available users in the system
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IEnumerable<UserDto> Get()
    {
        var users = dbContext.Users.ToList();

        return users.Select(u =>
        {
            var dto = mapper.Map<UserDto>(u);
            var claims = dbContext.UserClaims.Where(c => c.UserId == u.Id);
            dto.FirstName = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == JwtClaimTypes.GivenName)?.ClaimValue;
            dto.FamilyName = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName)?.ClaimValue;
            return dto;
        }).ToList();
    }
```

This is my startup config:

```
services.AddOData();

app.UseMvc(router =>
        {
            router.EnableDependencyInjection();
            router.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(100).Count().EnableContinueOnErrorHeader();
            router.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
        });

    IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        odataBuilder.EntitySet<IntentUser>("Users");
        return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I updated to OData 7.3.0 (and .Net Core 3.1), I have the same Problem.

If you use [Route(...)] and [ApiController] at the controler class, maybe thats the problem. Vanish Route attribute and ApiController attribute:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58849806/12858107