# How to register two controllers same name, different namespace in same ODATA EDM Model?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-core-odata

### Objective

The objective is to better understand how to develop modular (plugins by 3rd parties) approach to developing APIs, on top of ASP.NET Core.

To make plugin development easy to pick up it should rely on Conventions where possible, and  deliver high value.

OData's queryability and being an Standard remains a compelling improvement to REST, providing a lot of bang for effort.

### Issues

OData may be powerful, but the availability of current documentation remains sub par, hence unsure of its limits/capabilities.

Hence questions regarding what options one has to untangling routing issues due to conflicting endpoints from controllers in 3rd party modules.

Specifically:

- Q1: Can a single OData EDM model disambiguate between two Controllers with the same name in two different namespaces?
- Q2: Can one register an `ODataController` with a different *Route* than the `ODataController` name (eg route `Foo` points to `BarController`, when the convention is it would look for a `FooController`) *without* breaking default functionality? (eg: `$count` stops working for me)

  - Q2b: Even if we take over parsing incoming Uris into its odata path components as well as the logic it uses to find the relevant Controller?
- Q3: If it can't, would the more practical approach to loading Plugins be for each Plugin to register its own EDM models?
- Q4: Will using multiple EDM models work even if the second plugin/edm model has Controllers that exposes Models that has properties that refer back to Models exposed by Controllers in the base (or another dependency Plugin) EDM model?

  - Eg: Base EDM exposes `Person`s and `Address`es, and second plugin EDM exposes maybe `Customer`s, which has properties referencing `Person` and `Address`es types, provided by the base EDM?
  - (I'm *guessing* it will work, but not 100% sure...anybody see an issue with this?)
- Q5: How can one add new EDM models dynamically, resetting the routes?

  - For example if one uploaded a nuget package that was a plugin, and it contained its own EDM model describing its Models and Controllers...all this happening way after `after.Run()` was invoked, how can one kick the system in the head to refind/relearn what are valid routes?
- Q6: Why is $count only available on `ODataController`s that are registered by *Convention*, but doesn't work on those registered by `RouteAttribute`?

### Background

The latest(?) documentation I found in a blog post here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/

But it's just a blog post, and a lot remains missing to understand all the pieces and how they fit together.

### Process So Far

I'm listing my notes below to help others see better what I am trying, in case someone can see what I am obviously getting wrong.

And if it helps and you want working code, I've uploaded my investigation efforts (actually thrashingArounds):

https://github.com/skysgh/Spikes.AspNetCore.ODataRouting

### Setup

The default scenario in OData is to register EDM models with Controller Routes equal to the prefix of the name of the Controller.

Eg:

```cs
static string ODataPrefixWithSlash = "api/odata/v{version}/"

class SomeModelController : ODataController {...}

//is registered in an EDM model using convention of matching prefix of controller name:
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
//to build a whole model:
builder.EntitySet<SomeModel>("SomeModel"); //This will get found
builder.EntitySet<SomeModel>("Renamed"); //Without further work causes 404 as route string != controller prefix
var edmModelA = builder.Build();

//and the model later registered as the source of OData routing info:
var mvcBuilder = builder.Services
                            .AddControllers()
                            .AddOData(
                                opt => opt.Count().Filter().Expand().Select().OrderBy().SetMaxTop(5)
                                //Add Module/PluginA Routes:
                                .AddRouteComponents(AppAPIConstants.ODataPrefixWithSlash,edmModelA);
```

if one has enabled

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(); 
app.UseODataRouteDebug();
```

one can navigate to `~odata` and see the controller's Endpoints listed as:

```
~api/odata/v{version}/SomeModel
~api/odata/v{version}/SomeModel/$count <- note, showing for now (will break later...why?!)
```

### Controller Choice Process

An article exists that talks about how routing has been updated in OData v8 RC, relying on `RouteAttribute`

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/

After a lot of messing around, appears one can use a different name but

- only *IF* one starts the route with the same prefix used to register the EDM Model (eg: `api/odata/v{version}/`

```cs
    [ODataAttributeRouting]
    // Half Works
    // because the route starts with the same base as what the model was registered under
    // fools it(?) (where?) into accepting it as an Odata controller.
    // a) listed in ~/$odata as an odata controller (under api/odata/v{version}
    // b) acting as an Odata controller (returning odata wrapper in json)
    // c) but no default queryability (doesn't accept or list /$count)
    // as the route starts with same prefix
    // as Convention used when registereing EDM model
    // But $count doesn't work!
    [Route(AppAPIConstants.ODataPrefixWithSlash + "Renamed5")]
    public class ValuesA5Controller : ODataController{
        [EnableQuery(PageSize = 100)]
        [HttpGet("")]
        [HttpGet("Get")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(FakeDataBuilder.Get());
        }    
    }
```

The above permits registering the `ODataController` in the EDM model as follows:

```cs
builder.EntitySet<SomeModel>("Renamed5");
```

But it only *HALF* works.

- it is listed as an OData Controller in `$odata`. ok.
- it is acting (mostly) as an ODataController in that it accepts most OData commands $select, $filter, etc.
- But it is failing at offering $count for some reason:

```
~api/odata/v{version}/Renamed5 <- showing, same as it was doing for earlier SomeModelController 
~api/odata/v{version}/Renamed5/$count <- not showing, even though endpoint decorated with [EnableQuery].
```

### Options?

#### Option A: More Route information

I suspect that one could decorate the Get method with more routes to enable $count:

```
        [EnableQuery(PageSize = 100)]
        [HttpGet("")]
        [HttpGet("Get")]
        [HttpGet("$count") ??? <- really???
        public IActionResult Get() {....}
```

Certainly wish to avoid adding more codes as workaround (eg: what was tried here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73042175/19926885)

but even if either worked, its *more* code, more sources of errors, etc. to watch out for.
If at all possible I'd like the least code, the most convention, while not locking in controller names.

#### Option B: Controller Selection process

As I said earlier, I don't know how or where the odata framework is magically matching "SomeModel" to "SomeModelController".

In an article I came across (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/)
I saw mention of `AttributeRoutingConvention: IODataControllerActionConvention`  which maybe could be put to use, but the blog post
didn't show when/how it could be registered, or replaced so have not been able to progress in that direction yet.
Also, iterating through registered Services I don't see anything inheriting from `IODataControllerActionConvention`. What's going on?

What I do see is:

```
//not sure yet what these do
IODataQueryRequestParser
IODataTemplateTranslator : Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Template.DefaultODataTemplateTranslator
IODataPathTemplateParser : Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Parser.DefaultODataPathTemplateParser`
```

But I don't have documentation on how they work, what they are for, etc.

### Where next?

- First of all THANK YOU for taking the time to read this long question!
- Second, if you have advice as how I not thinking right as to how to solve the problem, that would help.
- Third, if you are able to provide answers to the questions...wow. It's been a while I've looked for answers to this!

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to recognise the following basic misunderstandings on my part.

- OData routing not something else but *is* an instance of the underlying WebAPI Routing
- When one registers an EDM and providing the route prefix (`"api/odata/v{version}"`), it's just registering `"~/api/odata/v{version}/~"` as an action/route filter.
- If you don't provide a `[RouteAttribute]` the convention is that it will make it up the Route segment from the Controller name (eg: 'PersonController' means that  'Person' will be used.
- If you do provide a `[RouteAttribute]` on the Controller, you are saying this is the *full* (not a suffix!) route -- even if you provided a prefix when registering the EDM model.... To underline that point: just because `HttpGet(...)` acts as a suffix to the `Route`, doesn't meant the `Route` does too.
- Which means that if it doesn't start with [Route("api/odata/v{version}")] -- maybe is just `[Route("Renamed6")]` -- it **doesn't match the route prefix used to register the edm model, so won't be handled by the models handler...so all it's doing is acting like all WebAPI controllers are doing and registers *another* route (whatever you gave), but won't consider it worthy of being OData queryability enabled....
- So your route has to be `[Route("api/odata/v{version}/Renamed6")]`.

Other than that, basics are that you'll get it confused if you register two models one with

- "`api/odata/v{version}`", and another with
- "`api/odata/v{version}/plugin`".
  The first handler/whatever (i don't know what's behind the scenes here) will probably try to capture requests to plugin and not find a controller called "*Plugin*Controller". I'm just guessing.

Finally, I think I saw issues with leaving dynamics tokens at the end for some reason. I had to change from using `api/odata/PluginA/v{version}` to `api/odata/v{version}/PluginA` . Not clear why.

Admittedly I still need to know a LOT more about the routing mechanism, but for now, this gets me forward again.

PS: Also...use Constants for building route strings. Turns out that Typos can really waste a lot of time :-(